# Not able to read the values of a key in python dictionary

Tags: python

the code is able to read the values of the first key but not the second key onwards.

```
#join_tables =  {'table_e_input_cols': [' e.rowkey', ' e.branchsequencenumber'], 'table_e1_input_cols': [' e1.branchsequencenumber']}           
i=0
for k,v in join_tables.items():
    print(table_e_input_cols[i].split(sep='.'))
    print(table_e1_input_cols[i].split(sep='.'))
    i = i+1
```

Error that am getting is:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_31619/2960019421.py in <cell line: 20>()
     20 for k,v in join_tables.items():
     21     print(table_e_input_cols[i].split(sep='.'))
---> 22     print(table_e1_input_cols[i].split(sep='.'))
     23     i = i+1
     24     #print(k)

NameError: name 'table_e1_input_cols' is not defined
```

Comment: Your key is "v"

Comment: Why are you iterating through dict items only to try to refer to them directly 2 lines later? Use the objects you get from iterator - `print(v[0].split(sep='.')); print(v[1].split(sep='.'))`

Comment: ```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_31619/2436809718.py in <cell line: 20>()
     19 i=0
     20 for k,v in join_tables.items():
---> 21     print(v[0].split(sep='.')); print(v[1].split(sep='.'))
     22     #print(table_e_input_cols[i].split(sep='.'))
     23     #print(table_e1_input_cols[i].split(sep='.'))

IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: You created a loop with `k` and `v`. Why aren't you using them?

Comment: @wander95 am using v right? How else do you want me to use them?

Comment: 'table_e_input_cols' and 'table_e1_input_cols' is not a variable names.

Answer (score 1):

When I try to uncomment the first line and run your code I get the following error:

```py
NameError: name 'table_e_input_cols' is not defined
```

Most likely that had been defined somewhere else earlier in your code, which is why you're not getting an error for the first key.

As you are already iterating over the key and values it would be easier to print out the values as such:

```py
join_tables =  {'table_e_input_cols': [' e.rowkey', ' e.branchsequencenumber'], 'table_e1_input_cols': [' e1.branchsequencenumber', ' e1.ranchsequencenumber']}           

for k,v in join_tables.items():
    print(f"Key is {key} and value is {v}")
```

If you want to iterate over every value independently:

```py
join_tables =  {'table_e_input_cols': [' e.rowkey', ' e.branchsequencenumber'], 'table_e1_input_cols': [' e1.branchsequencenumber', ' e1.ranchsequencenumber']}           

for k,v in join_tables.items():
    for index, item in enumerate(v):
        print(f"Key is {key} and index {index} of value is {item}")
```

Comment: table_e_input_cols is the first key in of the dict join_tables 

And I am able to access the key and the values but thats not I want, am looking the seperate the prefix from each element of the values of the key

Comment: Yes, I understand, however that is not how you access keys in your dictionary. Like I mentioned in the post when I run you your code `table_e_input_cols` gives me a `NameError` as it is not defined, if this is not the case for you, this is because you have defined it somewhere earlier.

To separate the prefix (I will assume remove) from each item in values, you can simply iterate over the dictionary and update the values for each item and reassign it to the dictionary. I will assume a prefix always exists.

```
for k, v in d.items():
    d[k] = [x.split('.')[1] for x in v]
```

Answer (score 1):

When you use the syntax `for k,v in join_tables.items():` the variables you have available to you in the for loop are ONLY `k` (the key) and `v` (the value) of each of the k-v pairs in the dict. So trying to use the actual name in the loop is not possible, python only knows k and v.

The other issue is that each value is an array and you're trying to split an array at a `.` and this is not going to be possible, you need to iterate over the array, not the dictionary.

Based on the clarification in the comment:

```
{k:[item.split('.')[1] for item in v] for k,v in join_tables.items()}
```

This puts it back into a dictionary bc there's no super clean way to turn a string into a variable name in python, but it should give you the format you want for the arrays.

To get the desired printout:

```
for k,v in join_tables.items():
    print(f"{k} = {[item.split('.')[1] for item in v]}")
```

Comment: Input is: 
join_tables =  {'table_e_input_cols': [' e.rowkey', ' e.branchsequencenumber'], 'table_e1_input_cols': [' e1.branchsequencenumber']}

Output am looking for: 
table_e_input_cols = ['rowkey', 'branchsequencenumber']
table_e1_input_cols = ['branchsequencenumber']

Comment: Ah, will edit my answer give me a sec

Comment: This is the error that am getting on executing your code     

 
     18 #join_tables =  {'table_e_input_cols': [' e.rowkey', ' e.branchsequencenumber'], 'table_e1_input_cols': [' e1.branchsequencenumber']}
---> 19 {k:v.split('.')[1] for k,v in join_tables}
     20 '''i=0
     21 for k,v in join_tables.items():

ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

Comment: yeah sorry, posted an edit - try that!

Comment: output is still a dictonary, I not only need the output but I need the value of the key as well
Later on am calling it here: table2_allcols = ['orderid', 'partitionid'] + join_tables['table_e_input_cols']

Comment: Hm, I don't think I entirely understand why you just need that data output to the screen but I posted an edit to give you that.

Comment: am getting the desired output but can we make it as declaration? Like can we make the output of a code as declaration so that it can be used later on?

Answer (score 0):

`table_e_input_cols` and `table_e1_input_cols` is not a variable names, so it goes to `NameError: name 'table_e1_input_cols' is not defined`. So I think this probably you want to achieve.

```
join_tables =  {'table_e_input_cols': [' e.rowkey', ' e.branchsequencenumber'], 'table_e1_input_cols': [' e1.branchsequencenumber']}

for k, v in join_tables.items():
    for i in v:
        print(i.split('.'))

# ['e', 'rowkey']
# ['e', 'branchsequencenumber']
# ['e1', 'branchsequencenumber']
```

Or something like this:

```
join_tables =  {'table_e_input_cols': [' e.rowkey', ' e.branchsequencenumber'], 'table_e1_input_cols': [' e1.branchsequencenumber']}

print(join_tables['table_e_input_cols'][0].split('.'))
print(join_tables['table_e_input_cols'][1].split('.'))
print(join_tables['table_e1_input_cols'][0].split('.'))

# ['e', 'rowkey']
# ['e', 'branchsequencenumber']
# ['e1', 'branchsequencenumber']
```